# Trying to add $var to a URL in a Curl URL

Tags: php, session, curl

So I have looked through stack overflow and google and cant find a good example of what I need.

I have a URL within Curl and i have a session variable i need to add to the URL (print out as string).

**Question**

how do i do this?

Here is my code

```
 <?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['userID'];
$userId = $_SESSION['userID'];

$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/$userId.xml';
```

**I have tried**

```
$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/echo $userId.xml';
```

**and**

```
$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/<?php echo $userId ?>.xml';
```

**UPDATE**

Ok full code, so if I change the URL to

`$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/1.xml';`

everything works, however I need the code to be dynamic depending on the session var

currently the session var `$_SESSION['userID'];` is 1

so the current code should work in the same way as if the URL was

```
 `$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/1.xml';`
```

but it dose not

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['userID'];
$userId = $_SESSION['userID'];

$service_url = "http://localhost/app/api/user/{$userId}.xml";
$session_cookie = file_get_contents( 'session_cookie.txt' );

// set up the request
$curl = curl_init( $service_url );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );  // have curl_exec return a string

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$session_cookie" ); // use the previously saved session

// make the request
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true ); // output to command line
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
print "RESPONSE:\n";
var_dump( $response );

$xml=simplexml_load_file("$service_url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->name . "<br>";
echo $xml->roles->item  . "<br>";
echo $xml->timezone . "<br>";
```

Instead I get errors

> Warning: simplexml_load_file

and

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/app/api/user/1%3Cbr%3E.xml&quot; in C:\wamp64\www\mytest\testfolder\authenticated.php on line 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$service_url  = "http://localhost/app/api/user/{$userId}.xml";
```

Comment: Sorry I have tried this and i get the error as mention in my updated question

Comment: It's because your urls looks like http://localhost/app/api/user/1%3Cbr%3E.xml&quot . The userId is "1<br>"

Comment: Nice, i understand, 5 mins Ill fix that

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.  Take the time to educate future readers on the difference between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change ' to ".
Let me explain why.

The difference ' to " is that " will parse $phpVariables.

So `$service_url  = "http://localhost/app/api/user/$userId.xml";` or `$service_url  = "http://localhost/app/api/user/{$userId}.xml";`

If for some reason you want to keep single quotes you can do this:

```
$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/'.$userId.'.xml';
```

Comment: good exponentiation, thanks. I have tried all of these. im getting errors, ill update my question with full code

Answer (score 0):

Why not CONCAT them?

```
$service_url  = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/'.$userId.'.xml';
```

Comment: have tried $service_url    = 'http://localhost/app/api/user/'.$userId.'.xml';  and that did not work